# How to show popup in tvOS?

Tags: uipopovercontroller, tvos, apple-tv

I am trying to show a popup when a UICollectionView cell, but I'm having no luck...

In iOS, I would usually use the modalPresentationStyle like this:

```
popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
```

but in tvOS this is not available.

I think showing a popup is possible by using

```
UIPopoverController
```

but it is giving me a warning that it is deprecated in tvOS 9.0. Is this something I can ignore and just use it?

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea how to make popup to work in tvOS?

**p.s.**

Does anyone know if there is a way for tvOS app to read data from external hardware through Apple TV USB?

Comment: I've used popover successfully using storyboard segue's.  I created a UIViewController and set the segue to be a Popover and it worked fine.  I have no depreciation warnings in Xcode either.   That being said I only added this to my codebase after tvOS 9.1 came out so maybe they recently added support?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is the [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html) introduced in TvOS 9.0

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                               message:@"This is an alert."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

Popovers are not available on tvOS.  You could probably build a custom presentation that had a similar appearance, but it would probably be non-trivial.